# Understanding ReactElement proptype

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am playing around with `material-ui`to learn about React. And I am wondering why I get the following error message :

`Invalid prop 'rightIconButton' of type 'function' supplied to 'ListItem', expected a single ReactElement.`

When I use a stateless component it work just fine but what if I need to have a stateful component or I need to access the `props` object.

How should it be done correctly?

```
class ParticipantList extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
        <List>
            {this.props.participants.map(function(participant){
                return (
                    <ListItem key={participant._id} 
                    primaryText={participant.fullname()} 
                    rightIconButton={participant.needHelp ? rightIconMenu : null} 
                    />);
            })}
      </List>
    );
  }
}

class rightIconMenu extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <IconMenu iconButtonElement={menuIconButton}>
        <MenuItem>Action</MenuItem>
      </IconMenu>
    ); 
  }
};

const menuIconButton = ( 
      <IconButton
        touch={true}
        tooltip="more"
        tooltipPosition="bottom-left"
      >
        <ActionGrade color={pinkA200} />
      </IconButton>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `rightIconMenu` is a class. In JavaScript land, a class is essentially a JavaScript function, and at times, it is *literally* a JavaScript function (that is, if you are compiling ES6/ES2015/ES.next down to ES5).

Hence why the error message is saying `'rightIconButton' of type 'function' supplied to 'ListItem'`. The identifier, `rightIconButton`, represents an uninitialized class, which, if you recall, is essentially a function. Based on `ListItem`'s definition, `rightIconButton` *must* to be a React element, and not anything else, be it a string, number or a function.

In React, a way to suppress this error is to actually initialize said class (that semantically represents a component) using the following syntax:

```
<rightIconButton />
{/* Just be sure to supply any necessary props */}
```

And also, depending on the PropType defined in the `ListItem` component, double check with the library to confirm whether or not `rightIconButton` is optional. If it is not optional, then `null` may equally raise an error. Fortunately, a workaround may simply involve supplying an empty `span`, like so:

```
rightIconButton={participant.needHelp ? <rightIconMenu /> : <span />}
```